# Waiting for parameter to be valued in Java

Tags: java, input, java-8

I recently starting to learn JAVA and I tried to create a little shell-like program (I don't rely on system shell for executing command).

I managed to get the basic I/O thing to work but I'm stuck in the following situation :

Let's say I use the command "makeFile path/to/file" the command will check if the exists and ask "File already exists ! Do you want to erase it ? Y/N"

My issue is to wait for the user inputting Y, N or anything else without locking the shell interface (A JTextArea).

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public abstract class Command {

private final String bin;
protected Shell shell;

public Command(Shell shell, final String bin) {
    this.shell = shell;
    this.bin = bin;
}

String getBin() {
    return this.bin;
}

protected String ask(String question) {
    shell.setQuestionAsked(true);
    shell.setResponse("");
    shell.write(question);
    String response = shell.getResponse();

    while(response.isEmpty()) {
        response = shell.getResponse();
    }

    shell.setQuestionAsked(false);
    return response;
}

public abstract void execute(StringTokenizer stringTokenizer);    
}
```

I tried to find solution in Concurrency / Threading but can't find a solution.

In the light @Holger comment, this is the GUI Code part, as you can see a Listener already exists. My issue lay in the fact that when a command ask an user input with the ask method shown above the execution will not wait for the user input and just go on or in the current the while(response.isEmpty()) cause a deadlock.

So I'm looking for a solution to hold the ask() method's execution until the user press enter in the GUI.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection;
import java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.io.IOException;


public class ShellPanel extends Shell {

    private JTextArea shellArea;
    private JPanel panel;
    private JScrollPane scrollPanel;

    private int bufferLength = 0;
    private String oldText = "";

    ShellPanel() {


        shellArea.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                super.keyPressed(e);

                switch (e.getKeyCode()) {

                    case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                    case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:

                        e.consume();

                        break;
                    case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:

                        if (shellArea.getCaretPosition() <= bufferLength) {
                            e.consume();
                        }

                        break;

                    case KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE:

                        if (shellArea.getText().length() <= bufferLength) {
                            e.consume();
                        }

                        break;
                    case KeyEvent.VK_DELETE:
                        break;
                    case KeyEvent.VK_ENTER:
                        read(getNewInput());
                        updateReferences();
                        e.consume();
                        break;
                    case KeyEvent.VK_HOME:
                        shellArea.setCaretPosition(bufferLength);
                        break;
                }

            }

        });

        shellArea.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                super.mouseClicked(e);

                switch (e.getButton()) {
                    case MouseEvent.BUTTON3:

                        String selected = shellArea.getSelectedText();
                        StringSelection selection = new StringSelection(selected);

                        if (!selected.isEmpty()) {
                            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(selection, selection);
                        }

                        try {
                            String clip = (String) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);

                            if (!clip.isEmpty()) {
                                shellArea.append(clip);
                            }

                        } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException | IOException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
        init();
        updateReferences();
    }

    JPanel getPanel() {
        return panel;
    }

    private void updateReferences() {
        oldText = shellArea.getText();
        bufferLength = oldText.length();
        shellArea.setCaretPosition(bufferLength);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(String content) {
        shellArea.append(content);
        updateReferences();
    }

    private String getNewInput() {
        return this.shellArea.getText().replace(this.oldText, "");
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        this.shellArea.setText("");
    }
   }
```

Thanks

Comment: Don’t wait. Add a listener to the text area that will be called when an event occurred and may perform the desired action if the event implies the necessary prerequisite, i.e. that `Y` or `N` has been entered.

Comment: Thanks @Holger, I forgot to mention that a listener is already present, I will add the GUI code to clarify my statement

Comment: You need to do this in a separate thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, you should avoid program logic that has to wait for a UI event instead of letting the appropriate event listener trigger the subsequent action.

The wait logic is similar to opening a modal dialog, whereas the opening method will return when the dialog has been closed. In the case of `JOptionPane.showInputDialog`, it will even return the entered value. This logic has been abstracted in Java 7 to allow arbitrary “wait for an event” scenarios. Here is a self-contained example:

```
public class WaitForInput {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame frame=new JFrame("Example");
            JTextArea ta=new JTextArea(20,40);
            ta.setEditable(false);
            frame.setContentPane(new JScrollPane(ta));
            frame.pack();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            char result = waitForInput(ta, "Press Y or N",
                ch -> Character.toUpperCase(ch)=='Y' || Character.toUpperCase(ch)=='N');
            waitForInput(ta,
                "You pressed "+result+", press Enter to continue", ch -> ch==10);
            ta.append("Ok, I'm happy... Close window to quit");
        });
    }
    static char waitForInput(JTextArea ta, String message, IntPredicate p) {
        ta.append(message);
        ta.append("\n");
        SecondaryLoop loop = ta.getToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().createSecondaryLoop();
        final class WaitOp extends KeyAdapter {
            char actualChar;
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                if(p.test(e.getKeyChar())) {
                    actualChar=e.getKeyChar();
                    loop.exit();
                }
            }
        }
        WaitOp op = new WaitOp();
        ta.addKeyListener(op);
        loop.enter();
        ta.removeKeyListener(op);
        return op.actualChar;
    }
}
```

But it must be emphasized that unlike a modal dialog, there is no visual indicator that there is an action that has stopped in the middle, waiting for a particular input (unless you program it yourself). Also, the rest of the UI isn’t blocked and could spawn new actions that could also stop in the middle, waiting for a different event, bringing the program in an unmaintainable state.

That’s why this should be avoided whenever possible. But if you restrict its use to a maintainable minimum, it can be quite useful.

Comment: That's a perfect solution, plus the use of a lambda keep it simple. Thanks;